# Aligning select components in div horizontally using CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am not an expert in CSS. I have a [web app](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/sanfx/publish) using Vue.js, in which I am using [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org) component.

Earlier I was using the simple select component and I was able to align the label and the 2 select components alongside horizontally, now that I have switched to vue-multiselect, I can't figure out how should I align them horizontally.

**Updated based on the (deleted) answer**

```
  <template>
    <div id="select">
    <my-row>
        <my-col>
    <label> Source </label>
    </my-col>
    <my-col>
    <label>Project</label>
    </my-col>
    <my-col>
     <multiselect  
     placeholder="Select a Project" 
     v-model="selected" 
     :options="projects" 
     :searchable="true" 
     :custom-label="customLabel" 
     track-by="name" 
     @input="executeLoader"
     >
         <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="{ option }"><strong>{{ option.name }}</strong></template>

    </multiselect>
    </my-col>
    <my-col>
    <div class="round-button">
        <div class="round-button-circle">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/leftarrow.png"  alt="Reload" title="Sync with Github" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div> </my-col>
    <my-col>
    <label>Branch:</label>
    </my-col>
    <my-col>
    <multiselect 
    v-model="selectedBranch" 
    :options="branches"
    :max="3"
    :max-height="120"
    :customLabel="customLabel"
    track-by="name"
    @input="branchSelecter">
        <option disabled selected>Select a branch</option>
        <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="{ option }">{{ option.name }}</template>

    </multiselect>
    </my-col>
    </my-row>
    <br>
    <small>{{ message }}</small>
</div>

</template>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/sanfx/publish

Comment: so you're saying you want to align both of the select fields horizontally next to each other? or just the label next to the select field

Comment: You need to wrap your layout components in a `<row><col>first col here</col><col>second col here</col></row>` structure, regardless of what what elements you choose to use for it. Looking at very basic layout examples will help (and, IMHO, should have been done before asking). (Re)search is not optional on SO. You could use both `inline-block` and `flex` display rules to make them as you want.

Comment: @Keith label and select field as well

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu when you say `<row>` or `<col>` are you referring to make use of div tag ? To create row column setup!

Comment: You can use anything you want. `<div>`s, `<span>`s or `<abcd-xyz></abcd-xyz>`. The principle is the same. If you use custom elements, however, you might want to change their `display` to `inline-block` or `block`, as they have `inline` by default. If Vue has grid layout components, that's what you should use. If not, all you need is `display:flex; align-items: center;` on `<row>` and `display:block` on `<col>`. If you want them to wrap under a particular width, apply `flex-direction: column` to `<row>` using a `@media` query.